# D280 final, trying to subscribe to data from API (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, subscription

Project: Interactive world map
Use SVG map file to get country name
Use country name for an API call
Use information from API to update a text box with information from the API.

I am following a guide, but it seems to need to be able to call the `Subject()` method/module/type/other-thingy but I do not have this type so when I compile I fail. See image:

File name: api.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { __classPrivateFieldGet } from 'tslib';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchCountryInfo(country: string) {
    let api = "https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/";
    api = api + country + "?format=JSON";
    console.log(api);
    return this.http.get(api)
  }
  setWeatherData(country: string) {
    let subject = new Subject();
  
  this.fetchCountryInfo(country).subscribe(data: any) => {
    subject.next({
      country: data.name
    })
  }
}
}
```

file name: map-world.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-world-map',
  templateUrl: './world-map.component.html',
  styleUrl: './world-map.component.css'
})
export class WorldMapComponent {
constructor(private apiService: ApiService){}

  getInfo(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    this.apiService.fetchCountryInfo(event.target.id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
}
```

I've tried building as shown. This causes the error in the image. I expected that but was hopeful.

Then I tried updating the "information box" inside of the subscription function. Expected this to update the text box but it can not since it seems to not be able to read the DOM from inside the subscription.

I've tried passing the DOM as a variable into the subscription. I didn't expect this to work and I probably didn't do it right.

I've tried returning the subscription to a variable. I thought this would let me read the data but I think what I got was just the promise of data that never gets followed up on.

I've tried formatting said observable into JSON but it just becomes a "safesubscription2." I didn't expect this to work but I wanted to try anything I could think of before I asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it. Here is the answer.

`import { Subject} from 'rxjs';`

just needed to `import Subject();`